# Define a \newcommand to incorporate colors in \myvariables

Tags: macros

I use LaTeX to write my job applications. Since I have more than 50 places to apply for, I like to define variables, such as: \targetorg, \website, \mysignature etc. Since these are sensitive portions of the letters, I would like to be able to define these variables such that they easily can stick out.(*by means of a color for example.*)
So far what I have been doing is the following:

```
\newcommand{\mycolor}{\color{blue}}  
\newcommand{\defaultcolor}{\color{black}}
\newcommand{\targetorg}{\mycolor "Name of organization I am applying work for" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\myname}{\mycolor "my name" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\job}{\mycolor "type of work" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\place}{\mycolor "location of organization" \defaultcolor}
```

This would then be used as follows:

```
begin{document}
Hi,  
My name is \myname and would like to apply as \job for \targetorg in \place. 
end{document}
```

In this manner, when I compile my document, the various defined variables stick out so I can spot quickly if there are any mess ups and adjust accordingly. After I am done with double checking the work, I then redefine \mycolor to black so that the text is in one uniform color. The way I have done it now works perfectly, except that from a coding perspective it looks primitive to always have to include {\mycolor ... \defaultcolor} for every new instance of \newcommand.
**Question:**
I would like to ask if there is a way to make a \newcommand that would automatically incorporate these color definitions within itself.  Ultimately I would like to do the following: 
  `\newcmdcolor{\targetorg}{"Name of organization I am applying work for"}`
which should be the exact equivalent of:
  `\newcommand{\targetorg}{\mycolor "Name of organization I am applying work for" \defaultcolor}`
So how do a define such a \newcmdcolor?
  `\newcommand{\newcmdcolor}{??????}`

**MWE**
I discussed above the essential aspects of the code. For the sake of complying to the MWE standards, I hereby produce a full working sample which can be copy-pasted to your convenience:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{\color{blue}}  
\newcommand{\defaultcolor}{\color{black}}
\newcommand{\targetorg}{\mycolor "Dummy Organization" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\myname}{\mycolor "Dummy Name" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\job}{\mycolor "Dummy Work" \defaultcolor}
\newcommand{\place}{\mycolor "Dummy Location" \defaultcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
To whom it may concern,\\\indent
My name is \myname\, and I would like to apply for \job\, at \targetorg\, in \place.\\
Sincerely,\\
\myname
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\textcolor` command will perhaps make things look a bit better, i.e. `\newcommand\newcmdcolor{\textcolor{\mycolor}{Name of organization}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Just say `\newcolorcmd{category}{"Text"}` and you will get a new command `\category` which will output the corresponding text.

Basically one could also use Torbjorn T's. proposition

Using the same color for `\mycolor` is not encouraged however, so there should be an additional argument to the command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcommand{\mycolor}{blue}  
\newcommand{\defaultcolor}{black}
%\newcommand{\targetorg}{\mycolor "Name of organization I am applying work for" \defaultcolor}
%\newcommand{\myname}{\mycolor "my name" \defaultcolor}
%\newcommand{\job}{\mycolor "type of work" \defaultcolor}
%\newcommand{\place}{\mycolor "location of organization" \defaultcolor}

\newrobustcmd{\newcolorcmd}[2]{%
\long\csgdef{#1}{\textcolor{\mycolor}{#2}}%
}%

\newcolorcmd{job}{"Type of work"}%
\newcolorcmd{myname}{"My name"}%


\begin{document}


\job

\myname%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The key is using `\textcolor`, rather than `\color` and switching back to the default color. Adding a switch will allow for easy reformatting when you don't want to color the strings any more.

The use of the `\perhapscolorize` macro avoids using colors when not wanted (so no `\textcolor{black}` will be performed when `\ifcolorize` is false.

```
\newcommand{\newcmdcolor}[3]{% #1 is the command, #2 is the color, #3 is the text
  \newcommand{#1}{\perhapscolorize{#2}{#3}}%
}

\makeatletter
% The helper macro
\newcommand{\perhapscolorize}[1]{%
  \ifcolorize
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\textcolor{#1}}%
  {\@firstofone}%
}
\makeatother
% the conditional
\newif\ifcolorize

% comment the following if you don't want colors
\colorizetrue
```

Complete example, showing that you can turn colors on and off with `\colorizetrue` and `\colorizefalse`; however, you'll probably just comment out the `\colorizetrue` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\newcmdcolor}[3]{% #1 is the command, #2 is the color, #3 is the text
  \newcommand{#1}{\perhapscolorize{#2}{#3}}%
}

\makeatletter
% The helper macro
\newcommand{\perhapscolorize}[1]{%
  \ifcolorize
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\textcolor{#1}}%
  {\@firstofone}%
}
\makeatother
% the conditional
\newif\ifcolorize

% comment the following if you don't want colors
\colorizetrue

\newcmdcolor{\targetorg}{blue}{Name of organization I am applying work for}
\newcmdcolor{\myname}{red}{my name}
\newcmdcolor{\job}{green}{type of work}
\newcmdcolor{\place}{black!50}{location of organization}

\begin{document}

Hi, My name is \myname{} and would like to apply as \job{} for \targetorg{} in \place. 

\colorizefalse

Hi, My name is \myname{} and would like to apply as \job{} for \targetorg{} in \place. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different version, where the color for a particular command is stated only if different from `\mycolor` (which must be previously defined):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\newcmdcolor}[3][\mycolor]{%
  % #1 is the (optional) color, #2 is the command, #3 is the text
  \newcommand{#2}{\perhapscolorize{#1}{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{blue}

\makeatletter
% The helper macro
\newcommand{\perhapscolorize}[1]{%
  \ifcolorize
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\textcolor{#1}}%
  {\@firstofone}%
}
\makeatother
% the conditional
\newif\ifcolorize

% comment the following if you don't want colors
\colorizetrue

% the first three will use \mycolor, the last one a different color
\newcmdcolor{\targetorg}{Name of organization I am applying work for}
\newcmdcolor{\myname}{my name}
\newcmdcolor{\job}{type of work}
\newcmdcolor[red]{\place}{location of organization}

\begin{document}

Hi, My name is \myname{} and would like to apply as \job{} for \targetorg{} in \place. 

\colorizefalse

Hi, My name is \myname{} and would like to apply as \job{} for \targetorg{} in \place. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will implement the ideas provided, however it is not answering the actual question I had. My question revolves around avoiding to use a color command in every new variable that needs to be defined. I need a new version of \newcommand which Christian Hupher provided.

Comment: @Gnam I'll add a different version that uses a standard color by default, but can accept a different one.

Answer (score 1):

As far I don't know your documentclass or any other related question. However I want to provide some useful hints from my point of view.

1. I would define a global if clause which setup the color.
2. Instead of using `\newcommand{\targetorg}` I would define a command `\targetorg`, which uses the organisation, e.g.: \targetorg{Name of Org}

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xspace}
\newif\ifhighlightsensitive
\highlightsensitivetrue
\highlightsensitivefalse

\let\mycolor\relax
\definecolor{mycolorname}{named}{black}
\ifhighlightsensitive
  \definecolor{mycolorname}{named}{blue}
\fi

\makeatletter

\let\@targetorg\relax
\newcommand{\targetorg}[1]{\gdef\@targetorg{#1}}
\newcommand\printtargetorg{\textcolor{mycolorname}{\@targetorg}\xspace}

\let\@myname\relax
\newcommand{\myname}[1]{\gdef\@myname{#1}}
\newcommand\printmyname{\textcolor{mycolorname}{\@myname}\xspace}

\let\@job\relax
\newcommand{\job}[1]{\gdef\@job{#1}}
\newcommand\printjob{\textcolor{mycolorname}{\@job}\xspace}

\let\@place\relax
\newcommand{\place}[1]{\gdef\@place{#1}}
\newcommand\printplace{\textcolor{mycolorname}{\@place}\xspace}
\makeatother

\targetorg{Name of organization I am applying work for}
\myname{my name}
\job{type of work}
\place{location of organization}
\begin{document}
Hi,  

My name is \printmyname and would like to apply as \printjob for \printtargetorg in \printplace. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why point number two would be more efficient?

Comment: @Gnam: So you can manipulate every string in your manner.